# How To Test PHP Bitwise Function Input Parameters

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or, input-parameters

Sometimes in programming they allow one to chain parameters in a single function input variable like the second input variable below:

```
define('FLAGA',40);
define('FLAGB',10);
define('FLAGC',3);
function foo($sFile, $vFlags) {
  // do something
}
foo('test.txt',FLAGA | FLAGB | FLAGC);
```

PHP calls this single pipe character `(|)` the Bitwise `OR` operator. How do I now add something inside `foo()` to test `$vFlags` to see which flags were set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll find that flags like this are normally defined as powers of 2, e.g.:

```
define('FLAGA',1);
define('FLAGB',2);
define('FLAGC',4); /* then 8, 16, 32, etc... */
```

As you rightly stated, these can be combined by using a bitwise OR operator:

```
foo('test.txt',FLAGA | FLAGB | FLAGC);
```

To test these flags inside your function, you need to use a bitwise AND operator as follows:

```
function foo($sFile, $vFlags) {
  if ($vFlags & FLAGA) {
    // FLAGA was set
  }
  if ($vFlags & FLAGB) {
    // FLAGB was set
  }
  //// etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "flags" parameter would be called a *bitmask*. A single byte contains 8 bits which are either set or not set. You simply assign your own meaning to every bit; if it's set it means *yes* for that particular bit, otherwise *no*.

So you need to start by defining your flags with the correct values which set the right bits; just arbitrary numbers won't combine together in the right ways:

```
define('FLAGA', 1);  // 00000001
define('FLAGB', 2);  // 00000010
define('FLAGC', 4);  // 00000100
define('FLAGD', 8);  // 00001000
```

Given the above, `FLAGB | FLAGD` creates a bit mask with the second and forth bit set (`00001010`). You need to get somewhat comfortable with converting between base 2 (binary) and base 10 (decimal) for this.

To test for this, you use `&`:

```
$flags = FLAGB | FLAGD;

if ($flags & FLAGA) {
    echo 'flag A is set';
}

if ($flags & FLAGB) {
    echo 'flag B is set';
}

..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the bitwise `AND` operator `&`:

```
define('FLAGA',40);
define('FLAGB',10);
define('FLAGC',3);

function foo($sFile, $vFlags) {
  if ($vFlags & FLAGA) {
    echo "FLAGA is set\n";
  }
  if ($vFlags & FLAGB) {
    echo "FLAGB is set\n";
  }
  if ($vFlags & FLAGC) {
    echo "FLAGC is set\n";
  }
}
foo('test.txt',FLAGA | FLAGB | FLAGC);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/SnQQus)

That said, bitwise operations necessarily work in terms of binary, where each bit represents a power of 2. So, you are typically going to want to define flags in powers of 2, as in

```
define('FLAGA',1);
define('FLAGB',2);
define('FLAGC',4);
define('FLAGD',8); // etc.
```

Otherwise, imagine this scenario:

```
define('FLAGA',8);
define('FLAGB',32);
define('FLAGC',40);
```

If you have a value 40 for `$vFlags`, you can't tell what flags are set; it could be any of the following:

```
FLAGA & FLAGB
FLAGA & FLAGB & FLAGC
FLAGA & FLAGC
FLAGB & FLAGC
FLAGC
```

Comment: Remember type coersion in Php when unit-testing :)

The evaluated value of ($vFlags & FLAGC) results either in 0 (zero) or a non-zero integer. This will evaluate the same as a boolean, but if you're unit-testing and asserting a boolean value, the assertion will fail no matter what.

`$test = $vFlags & FLAGC;`
`assertTrue($test) // this will fail because $test is actually an integer, not a boolean`
`assertTrue($test == FLAGC) // this will work because now there is an actual boolean value`

`if($test){... // this will work because of type coersion`